# Can't compile and install ardour and jack2

Tags: 15.04, compiling, audio-jack, ardour, kylin

On the left is JACK and on the right is ARDOUR.[image: ERROR]

To compile JACK,`./configure --prefix=/usr/local/jack`,but `configure: error: ＊＊＊ a required header file is missing`,I don't know what header file is missing…
To create an application bundle for ardour,`./build --public --strip some`but there are so many errors…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Jack, the last message that you get is 
db.h... no
To install that header file, type:

```
sudo apt-get install libdb4.7-dev
```

The error ardour also points to libdb.

Comment: Oh…JACK compile successfully,but ardour have a new error…

Comment: @msy gave you a correct answer, which has solved your problem. If you have a new problem, then [ask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) a new question. Therefore, I have restored the old state of the question. Accept the answer as correct and give him an upvote. **;)**

Comment: @A.B. Got it.:)